# DateTime Python making a list with the current date and time and next couple of days

Tags: python, datetime

Im trying to make a list of the current date and the next 15 days. When I try to store it on a list I get a certain output when I write it to a file, which is listed in the image link. Also I want to get rid of the seconds and just keep the format of "year/month/date". How would I go along doing these? [File output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdU2r.png)

```
   import datetime
    room = []
    dated = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range(15): 
        dated += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        
        room.append(dated)
    
        
    
        with open('2dates.txt', 'w') as f:
          f.write(str(room))
        print(room)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make time to string , you need this .strftime() function
and this is my way to solve your question

```py
import datetime

dated = datetime.datetime.now()
day_difference = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
room = []
for i in range(15): 
    dated = dated + day_difference
    room.append(dated.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
with open('2dates.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(room))
```

- output

> ['2021-08-11', '2021-08-12', '2021-08-13', '2021-08-14', '2021-08-15', '2021-08-16', '2021-08-17', '2021-08-18', '2021-08-19', '2021-08-20', '2021-08-21', '2021-08-22', '2021-08-23', '2021-08-24', '2021-08-25']